# How to write a for loop to get the information across an entire table

Tags: anylogic

Previously I have imported my excel spreadsheet into the database the common way (by loading the whole spreadsheet). Now I want to get my information automatically from writing the code in main. I want to make a for loop to get the information from a table from an excel file. I'm using an excel file from the connectivity palette. So far, I have used

```
for (int i=7; i<27; i++) {
    insertInto(bed).columns(bed.apple).values(data.getCellNumericValue("Sheet1", i, 3)).execute();
    insertInto(bed).columns(bed.banana).values(data.getCellStringValue("Sheet1", i, 1)).execute();
}
```

but I think this will be too long if I do it for every column. What I want is to get the method to loop across all the rows, and all the columns in the table, instead of doing each single column.

Comment: It doesn't tell what you want to do

Comment: its been edited. is that clearer

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you might need to adjust it based on the API

```
for (int i=0; i<data.getNumberOfSheets() {
    for (int j=0; j<data.getLastRowNum(i); j++) {
        for (int k=0; k<data.getLastCellNum(j) {
            // access this cell using data.getCellNumericValue(i, j, k) (maybe j and k reversed, check the API)
        }
    }
}
```